# EmberJS - Prevent record with duplicate attributes being added to store

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, store

My first question here so please accept my apologies if this has been asked before and/or I am making some newbie mistake!

I am trying to get my head around EmberJS with a simple exercise. I am trying to create a list of keywords and I have the basic functionality working. I wish to allow the user to enter a comma separated list of keywords to the store, however, alert if the keyword is a duplicate.

So I have an ArrayController with an Actions object and within which I have a createKeyword function.

```
createKeyword: function() {

        // Get the keyword title set by the "New Keyword" text field
        var entered_value = this.get('newKeyword');

        if (!entered_value) { return false; }
        if (!entered_value.trim()) { return; }

        var entered_values = entered_value.split(",");

        for ( var i=0; i<entered_values.length; i++){

            var value = entered_values[i];

            value = value.replace(/\+|"|'/g," ");

            if ( ! value.trim() ){
                continue;
            }

            value = value.toUpperCase();

            alert( "Prior addition:" + this.get('length'));

            // Prevent duplicates being added
            if ( this.findBy('keyword',value) === undefined ) {

                // Create the new Keyword model
                var keyword = this.store.createRecord('keyword', {
                    value: value,
                    weighting: 1,
                    isNew: true
                });

                // Save the new model
                keyword.save();

                alert( "post addition:" + this.get('length') );

            }
            else {
                alert( "Keyword [" + value + "] already defined");
            }

        }


        // Clear the "New Keyword" text field
        this.set('newKeyword', '');

    }
```

I have a couple of alerts in there - one to display the array controller's length before I check for the value and subsequently createRecord on the store and one after. So I run this with 3 records, say 'tom','dick','harry' and if I add 'fred' to it, first alert is 3 and second alert is also 3 and fred appears.

I am confused as to why the 2nd alert is showing 3 and not 4 - I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that the arrayController has not yet been updated with the new record.

Secondly, if I restart then try adding fred,dick as an input, both get added, I would have thought fred should have been added and dick rejected as it was a duplicate.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the way you wrote your code and that you use an 'ArrayController`, I'm going to assume that the model for this particular route is all of your keywords. So the`model` hook is probably:

```
model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('keyword');
}
```

Assuming that, I think I can answer your questions.

First, the length doesn't change when you create the new record. It should increment from 3 to 4, but it doesn't. You are correct in assuming that the bindings haven't had time to update yet. You added the new record to the store, but the store hasn't had time to update the model for your controller yet because you still have control of the program flow. Most bindings are updated asynchronously in the run loop, so for many scenarios in Ember, you can't expect immediate updates.

Secondly, as for duplicates being added, it's hard to say but I think it's because you have a logic error.

```
// Prevent duplicates being added
if ( this.findBy('keyword',value) === undefined ) {
```

It seems to me as if you mistakenly put `keyword` instead of `value`. This might be just a typo when you were typing this question, but based on how you created your model, `keyword` is the type and `value` is the property.

Finally, a quick note: you shouldn't override the `isNew` property like you do when creating the new keyword. That will actually override the Ember-Data property with a permanent `true` value. (At least that's how I remember it working. I might be wrong, but it doesn't matter.) `isNew` is a computed property created by Ember-Data that will automatically update when the state of the object changes. Don't worry about setting it manually; just use the record as you normally would and Ember-Data will take care of the rest.